# Redis BITOP OR operation between different db keys

Tags: python, redis

I want to perform bitwise OR between keys stored in different db in redis.

```
r=redis.Redis(db=0)
r1=redis.Redis( db=1)
key1= r.keys('a')[0]
key2 = 'b'
r1.bitop('OR','dest',key1,key2)
```

But this will not work as key1 will be searched in db=1 instead of db=0. Any suggestion here.

Answer (score 0):

Copy one of the keys to the other database and do the bitwise operation there.